# VBScript file rename: “File Already Exists” error

Tags: vbscript

Files in folder D:\FOLDER01:

```
-  NAME TEST File01 12345.txt
-  NAME TEST File02 12345.txt
-  NAME TEST File03 12345.txt
-  NAME TEST File04 12345.txt
-  NAME TEST File05 12345.txt
```

How to make this script works?

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, folder, file, recentFile, folderName

folderName = "D:\FOLDER01\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)
Set recentFile = Nothing

For Each file In folder.Files
    Set recentFile = file
    If (InStr(recentFile, "NAME TEST") > 0) Then
        recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "NAME TEST ", "")
        recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, " 12345", "")
    End If
Next
```

"File Already Exists" error in line:

```
recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, " 12345", "")
```

Comment: You're renaming multiple files. At least two of them would have the same name after renaming the files. To make the script work: ensure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: You are correct, I am renaming multiple files in folder `D:\FOLDER01\.` But each file has unique file name, eg: `NAME TEST File01 12345.txt`, `NAME TEST File02 12345.txt`, `NAME TEST File03 12345.txt`, etc. So... it should be no "File Already Exists" error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I just re-created your scenario and ran your sample code. No error. Files renamed exactly as one would expect.

Comment: One again, you are correct. Sometime it run with "File Already Exists" error, another time run perfectly, and sometime only replace the first part, eg: `NAME TEST File03 12345.txt` become `File03 12345.txt` and NOT as expected `File03.txt` Don't know why this happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When renaming files, it is always possible the new name already exists in the output path. To overcome that, you can add a sequential number to the new file name like Windows does:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, folder, file, folderName, path, baseName, extension, newName, count

folderName = "D:\FOLDER01\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)

For Each file In folder.Files
    If (InStr(file.Name, "NAME TEST") > 0) Then
        path = file.ParentFolder & "\"                    'the folder this file is in
        baseName  = fso.GetBaseName(file.Name)            'the file name without extension
        extension = fso.GetExtensionName(file.Name)       'the extension without the dot
        If Len(extension) Then extension = "." & extension

        'removing the strings from the base name.
        baseName = Replace(baseName, "NAME TEST", "")
        baseName = Trim(Replace(baseName, "12345", ""))
        'the new filename with extension could be this
        newName = baseName & extension

        'to make certain this new name is unique, do the following:
        count = 1
        'test if this new name already exists and if so, append a sequence number to it "(x)"
        While fso.FileExists(path & newName)
            newName = baseName & "(" & count & ")" & extension
            count = count + 1
        Wend
        'here we should be quite certain the new name is not already in use, so update the file
        file.Name = newName
    End If
Next

Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```